# Count() in sql calculate

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I have a table `room` with the columns `room_id`, `hotel_id`, `status`.  I want to calculate how many rooms in each hotel have a `status` of `1`.

I suppose this is going to be with a `count()` function, but how do I use it?

I have this:

```
SELECT hotel_id, (SELECT count(status) FROM room WHERE room.status = '1')
FROM room
GROUP BY hotelID
```

but it counts *all* the rooms of all hotels that have `status = 1`, and I want all the rooms of *each* hotel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation.  That is when you nest a `case` statement in an aggregation function:

```
select hotel_id, sum(case when status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as status1
from room
group by hotelID;
```

The `case` returns `0` or `1` depending on the status.  The `sum()` then adds them all up.  If you want to use `count()`, you can do so by dropping the `else` clause (or using `else NULL`):

```
select hotel_id, count(case when status = 1 then 1 end) as status1
from room
group by hotelID;
```

I prefer the method with `sum()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to filter out the rest of the results:

```
select hotel_id, 
  (select count(status) from room sr where sr.status='1' and sr.hotel_id = room.hotelID) 
from room
group by hotelID
```

Comment: `and sr.hotel_id = room.hotelID` by using this it ensures that it will check every hotelid?

Comment: It's a subquery that will execute for every row of your results. I added to your where clause to only count the hotel_ids that pertained to the current row.